# Dynamic Form and Database Schema

Tags: html, mysql, sql, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I did a quick check and I could not find any questions similar to the one I am about to ask. I wish I could have been more specific in the title as it seems like a question that has been answered just shy of a million times.

I currently am having the dilemma of not knowing how to setup a schema for the following problem for a web app:

I have an online form that has users order custom tshirts with the following fields: Size, Color, Pocket.

Each user in the system can have different options from the first and the fields are dynamically generated

Examples:
User 1: Size[Small or Medium], Color[Grey or Black], Pocket[Square or Rectangle]

User 2: Size [Medium or Large], Color[Blue or Red], Pocket[Square or Triangle]

Every user can have completely different options and the options for the size, color and pocket are independent of each other.

Is this a possible solution to this problem?

Table:

id | user_id | Size | Size_options | Color | Color_options | Pocket | Pocket_options

I feel there is a better way to break these out even more and would be nice to have field for option value.

I will be using a MySql database.

This is just a small example of my problem and have forms with 50+ fields that all need to interchange like this one but are textboxes, checkboxes, radio buttons, and select drop-downs.

Thank You so much for reading and any advice that is given and I apologize for the length. I wanted to be clear on the issue I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is seperate table that stores properties

```
Properties
id
property name
property description
```

What goes in here? Things like Pocket shape, pocket color, shirt color, collar type etc.

Then you need another table to link the above with a particular item of clothing ordered by a user

```
cloth_properties
user_id (or more likely order id)
property_id  (foreign key properties)
property_value
```

This allows you to be in full control of what properties are being set or changed by the user and also makes it possible for you to add new properties dynamically.

Comment: Thank You! I am not sure I completely understand though and please forgive me as the write up you gave was good but I just want to be sure I understand correctly.

Where would the Blue go if it was a shirt color? Would that alone be a row in the Properties table?

Comment: There would be an entry in the cloth_properties table that has the property_id that corresponds to shirt color in it. The property value column would say blue (you probably might want to use actual color codes here)

Comment: Thank You! One last question. This form is going to have about 50 dynamic fields, and wouldn't this mean that there will be (50 * num of users) entries? Is that wasteful or too many?

Comment: That's not a worry at all. properly tuned databses can handle it.